# Call dynamic SOQL from other method in apex

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, method

Good Day everyone, I have a problem in regards with calling a method that contain a dynamic SOQL. To explain further, below is a sample code:

```
public class commonFunction {
  public static String whereInQueryString(String WhereField) {
    Set<String> tempWhereList = new Set<String>();  

    // process some data here
    tempWhereList.add('sample');
    tempWhereList.add('sample2');
    tempWhereList.add('sample3');
    QueryString = 'Select Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE ' + WhereField + ' IN '+ tempWhereList;
    return QueryString;
  }
}
```

After creating the above code, I call it from the other class.

```
String query = commonFunction.whereInQueryString('FirstName');
System.debug('query : ' + query);
```

The problem is that I encounter the error

```
expecting a colon, found '{'
```

I've tried to update the code to something like this

```
QueryString = 'Select Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE ' + WhereField + ' IN :tempWhereList';
```

But since, the `tempWhereList` is local variable I encounter error

```
Variable does not exist: tempWhereList
```

The given code is just a sample. I just want to ask what is the best thing to do. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

You can create `set<String>` and pass into method like this

```
Set<String>() tempWhereList  = new Set<String>();  
tempWhereList.add('sample');
tempWhereList.add('sample2');
tempWhereList.add('sample3');
```

And you class will be

```
public class commonFunction {
  public static String whereInQueryString(String WhereField, Set<String> tempWhereList) {

    String QueryString = 'Select Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE ' + WhereField + ' IN : tempWhereList ';
    return QueryString;
  }
}
```

Now in call you method like this

```
Set<String>() tempWhereList  = new Set<String>();  
tempWhereList.add('sample');
tempWhereList.add('sample2');
tempWhereList.add('sample3');
String query = commonFunction.whereInQueryString('FirstName', tempWhereList  );
System.debug('query : ' + query);
```

---

### Edit

Else return List of contacts.

```
public class commonFunction {
  public static List<contact> whereInQueryString(String WhereField) {
    Set<String> tempWhereList = new Set<String>();  

    // process some data here
    tempWhereList.add('sample');
    tempWhereList.add('sample2');
    tempWhereList.add('sample3');
    QueryString = 'Select Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE ' + WhereField + ' IN : tempWhereList';
    return Database.query(QueryString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I try to run this code and still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hope check my updated ans

Comment: This is what I did with my code in the first place. But, I am trying to change it to process those data inside my other function for some reason. Is it possible?

Comment: @Hope then do one thing Query inside that method and return the list

Comment: I believe this is a good idea to return the database.query instead of String. Thank you so much for help. +